# PHP - missing entries in Database (bind_param)

Tags: php

Good morning,
I try to fill up a database (with PHP and HTML) and followed a tutorial so far. 
After a few successful chapters I get stucked at the Point where I have to fill up the database with some data.
Everything seems working fine. But when I save entries it only stores 3 values. 
In my example are this the columns "id" "created_at" and "text".
The other columns stays empty. 
Iam using:

- PHP Version 7.1.14
- Apache WebServer 2.0 (on Windows)
- MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)

(german) [Tutorial](https://www.php-kurs.com/db-neuen-datensatz-speichern.htm)

```html
<?php
require ('dbconnect.php');
$db = mysqli_connect (MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_BENUTZER, MYSQL_KENNWORT, MYSQL_DATENBANK);
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    die('Sorry');
}    
$db->set_charset('utf8');
if (isset($_POST['aktion']) and ($_POST['aktion']=='speichern')) {
    $vorname = "";
    if (!isset($_POST['vorname'])) {
        $vorname = trim($_POST['vorname']); 
    }
 $email = "";
    $if (!isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }
    $nachname = "";
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    }
    $text = "";
    if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
        $text = trim($_POST['text']);
    }
 $funktion="";
 
    $created_at = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 
    
 if ( $vorname != '' or $name != '' or $created_at != '' or $text != '')
    {
     $einfuegen = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO gaestebuch (name, email, text, vorname, funktion, created_at) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,NOW())");
  $einfuegen->bind_param('sssss',  $vorname, $email, $text, $nachname,  $funktion);
  $einfuegen->execute();

 if ($einfuegen->execute()) {
            header('Location: config.php?aktion=feedbackgespeichert');
            die();
            echo "<h1>gespeichert</h1>";
        }
    } 
}
if (isset($_POST['aktion']) and $_POST['aktion']=='feedbackgespeichert') {
    echo "<p>Es liegen keine Daten vor :(</p>";
}
$daten = array();
  if ($erg = $db->query("SELECT * FROM gaestebuch")){
  if ($erg->num_rows) {
  while($datensatz = $erg->fetch_object()) {
            $daten[] = $datensatz;
        }
  $erg->free();
    } 
} 
if (!count($daten)) {
    echo "<p>no data :</p>";
}
else {
?>
 <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>name</th>
      <th>vorname</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>text</th>
      <th>funktion</th>
                <th>created_at</th>
      <th>deleted_at</th>
    
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
   <?php
   foreach ($daten as $inhalt){
  ?>
            <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $inhalt->id; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $inhalt->name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $inhalt->vorname; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $inhalt->email; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $inhalt->text; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $inhalt->funktion; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $inhalt->created_at; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $inhalt->deleted_at; ?></td>
            </tr>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php 
}
?> 
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Vorname: 
 <input type="text" name="vorname" id="vorname">
    </label>
 
    <label>Nachname: 
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </label>
 
  <label>email: 
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </label>
 
    <label>text: 
        <textarea name="text" id="text"></textarea>
    </label>
 
  <label>funktion: 
         <textarea name="funktion" id="funktion"></textarea>
    </label>
   <input type="hidden" name="aktion" value="speichern">
   <input type="submit" value="speichern">
</form>
```

Can anyone help me? :)

Comment: please link to the tutorial?

Comment: [Tutorial-Link](https://www.php-kurs.com/db-neuen-datensatz-speichern.htm) German tut

Comment: Nope, only one who can help is you. You have to *debug* your code to see where your values was set to empty. Mysqli does nothing of the kind, as you can guess.

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

Your 2 if conditions are logically wrong:

these

```
if (!isset($_POST['vorname'])) {
    $vorname = trim($_POST['vorname']); 
}
$email = "";
$if (!isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}
```

should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['vorname'])) {
    $vorname = trim($_POST['vorname']); 
}
$email = "";
$if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
}
```

Comment: They are already existing in my database. The entries in the columns stays empty after saving. It is like they never get in the POST function or get overwritten somehow.

Comment: Uhh how was it even possible to overlook these little ! scammers ^^
Thanks alot :)

Comment: @user9380299 happy to help it happens to me lots of times :P